# Implement OnCollectionChanged so that ListBox updates automatically WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

I have this object wrapper, whose instances I populate the collection with:

```
public class Multimedia : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   //... constructor
   //... getters and setters for the properties

   public void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      ObservableCollection<Multimedia> objSender = sender as ObservableCollection<Multimedia>;
      NotifyCollectionChangedAction action = e.Action;
   }
}
```

The collection:

```
public class MultiMediaList : ObservableCollection<Multimedia>
{
    //... constructor with creating several default objects of Multimedia

    public void addMedia(string title, string artist, string genre, MediaType type)
    {
        this.Add(new Multimedia(title, artist, genre, type));
    }
}
```

So, I have a ListBox that is bound to the collection. When I start up the app, the default values are shown. But when I add a new entry to the collection - the ListBox does not get updated with the new item.

I guess I have not implemented correctly the `OnCollectionChanged` method, but I cannot grasp an idea of how to do it, from the examples that I have seen online, because every case is so different.

**EDIT:**
Code-behind binding of the Collection and the ListBox:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MultiMediaList mediaList;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mediaList = new MultiMediaList();
        LB_media.ItemsSource = mediaList;
    }

    //...
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="LB_media" DisplayMemberPath="Title" ... />
```

Comment: You don't need `OnCollectionChanged` in `Multimedia` and `ObservableCollection<T>` already implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Seems problem is somewhere else. Can you show your XAML and bindings for `ListBox`?

Comment: @dkozl - I updated my question post.

Comment: When you add you use same instance of `mediaList`? Do you add asynchronously?

Comment: No, I don't have async methods. I did not understand your comment fully. You mean when I add in the `addMedia()` method? Is what you mean, that I add the new entry to a different instance of the `mediaList` collection?

Comment: What I mean is constructor the only place where you do `mediaList = new MultiMediaList();` and later on you just do `mediaList.addMedia(...)`. Can you show how you add item as well?

Comment: Yeah, I found my mistake. You were right. I have a separate window that opens, which has the fields for input and creation of new entry to the `mediaList`, and in the code-behind of this 2nd window I was creating a new instance of the collection. This was really not a problem that I was looking for. It is working fine now. Thank you very much!